# Is there any way to export an Excel table that contains images to LaTeX?

Tags: tables, graphics, excel

If I use the Excel2LaTeX addin, the images are not exported and the column is left empty.

Is there any way to export this table that contains images without having to export each image separately? Or would it be better to just save the Excel file as a PDF and merge with the document at the end?

Comment: If you save if as a pdf, you can do `\includegraphics` which is rather easy.  Can you post an image of what you want to export?

Comment: Is it easy to generate the graphs in [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)? The quality would be much better than exported images from Excel.